# Realloc double 2D array in C

Tags: c, malloc, coordinates, multidimensional-array, realloc

I wrote an function which should realloc the array for each input. I think that function works well, but when I'm trying to work with the array I got segmentation fault.

Input:

```
[1,2] [6,3] [2.5,3.5]
```

I have to check if the user enters input in the correct form `'[' number ',' number ']'`. I have to have at least 2 entries. The end of input isn't new line, but EOF (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).

My code:

```
double ** allocation (double ** field, int i)
{
   double x = 0, y = 0;
   char obr[1], cbr[1], col[1];

   while (scanf("%c%lf%c%lf%c", &obr, &x, &col, &y, &cbr) == 5)
   {
       if (col[0] != ',' || obr[0] != '[' || cbr[0] != ']')
           return 0;

       field = (double **) realloc(field, (i + 1) * sizeof(*field));
       if (field == NULL)
           return 0;

       field[i] = (double *)malloc(2 * sizeof(double));
       if (field[i] == 0)
           return 0;

       field[i][0] = x;
       field[i][1] = y;
       i++;
  }
  if (feof (stdin))
      return 0;

  return field;
}
```

And when I want to use this:

```
double min = sqrtf(powf(field[0][0] - field[1][0], 2) + powf(field[0][1] - field[1][1], 2));
```

I will get my segmentation fault.

Comment: Is the issue that your `allocation` function returns a value of `1` while it's supposed to return a pointer to a `double` array?

Comment: (In addition) I guess the problem is that you modify `field` *locally* (by using `realloc`), and its new value gets discarded when you leave the function.

Comment: maybe `return 1;` -> `return field;`

Comment: all of you have right, but i tried do math function in function, same effect(segmentation fault), anyway I'll try to modify it.

Comment: I added `field = (double **) malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(*field));` before while, but still doesn't work, could somebody help me please?

Comment: If `realloc` returns `NULL`, you will have leaked whatever memory was previously allocated since you are overwriting `field`.

Answer (score 0):

From `man realloc` (emphasis mine):

> The realloc() function tries to change the size of the allocation pointed
>   to by ptr to size, and returns ptr.  If there is not enough room to
>   enlarge the memory allocation pointed to by ptr, **realloc() creates a new
>   allocation**, copies as much of the old data pointed to by ptr as will fit
>   to the new allocation, frees the old allocation, and returns a pointer to
>   the allocated memory.

You're not guaranteed to be using the same memory when you use `realloc`, you need to pass the pointer back for the case that it's been moved to a new location. You can check for success by checking whether it's a NULL pointer or not, too.

**tl;dr**: You need to use `return field` instead of `return 1` or `return 0`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner and I didnt get your hint.

Comment: No, my fault. You need to use `return` to pass it back, since the copy  of `field` that you get back once you use `realloc` is "lost" as soon as you use `return` and leave the function.

Comment: It still doesn't solve my problem. And I don't know why this ends by hitting `Enter`.