# Setup a 2D array, change size later - C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to declare a 2D array in C, then set its size later on? I know in C you have to deal with memory and such, but I cannot find answer to this question despite all my searching.

My current example is..

```
   int boardsize, linewin;
   char array[1][1];
   //boardsize is set within here.

   array = [boardsize][boardsize];
```

Comment: You are going to need to use memory allocation with `malloc()` and to use pointers to the allocated memory and treat the memory like a 2D array.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677566/malloc-a-2d-array-in-c which describes the procedure.  and this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt

Comment: c is much more machine-oriented and machine won't be happy with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C you will need to do your own dynamic array management using pointers.

See the following articles on how to go about doing so using an allocated memory area.

[Malloc a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677566/malloc-a-2d-array-in-c)

[Using malloc for allocation of multi-dimensional arrays with different row lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt)

Since you are looking to modify these, you may also need to use the `realloc()` function or the `free()` function to release allocated memory.

For information about using the realloc() function look at the following stack overflow.

[Realloc double 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299034/realloc-double-2d-array-in-c)

[two-dimensional dynamic array (realloc in c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036408/two-dimensional-dynamic-array-realloc-in-c)

**EDIT - Adding an example**

Here are two functions to `malloc()` a two dimensional array and to `realloc()` a two dimensional array.  You could actually just use the `realloc()` version if you pass a NULL pointer to `realloc2dCArray()` for the memory area to be reallocated.

What I have tried to do is to use a single `malloc()` and `realloc()` for all of the memory needed so that you can `free()` the memory with a single call to `free()`.

```
char **malloc2dCArray (int nRows, int nCols)
{
    // use a single malloc for the char pointers to the first char of each row
    // so we allocate space for the pointers and then space for the actual rows.
    char **pArray = malloc (sizeof(char *) * nRows + sizeof(char) * nCols * nRows);

    if (pArray) {
        // calculate offset to the beginning of the actual data space
        char *pOffset = (char *)(pArray + nRows);
        int   i;

        // fix up the pointers to the individual rows
        for (i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
            pArray[i] = pOffset;
            pOffset += nCols;
        }
    }

    return pArray;
}

char **realloc2dCArray (char **pOld, int nRows, int nCols)
{
    // use a single realloc for the char pointers to the first char of each row
    // so we reallocate space for the pointers and then space for the actual rows.
    char **pArray = realloc (pOld, sizeof(char *) * nRows + sizeof(char) * nCols * nRows);

    if (pArray) {
        // calculate offset to the beginning of the actual data space
        char *pOffset = (char *)(pArray + nRows);
        int   i;

        // fix up the pointers to the individual rows
        for (i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
            pArray[i] = pOffset;
            pOffset += nCols;
        }
    }

    return pArray;
}
```

To use these functions you would do something like the following:

```
char **pChars = malloc2dCArray (16, 8);
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        pChars[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

To do a `realloc()` you will want to check that the `realloc()` worked so use a temporary variable and check for NULL before using it.

```
{
    char **pChars2 = realloc2dCArray (pChars, 25, 8);
    if (pChars2) pChars = pChars2;
}
```

You could also just use the `realloc()` version if you provide a NULL pointer since `realloc()` will do a `malloc()` if the pointer to the memory to `realloc()` is NULL.

I did some testing of this using a debugger and it looks like it is working to me.

Comment: I am starting to understand what you are all saying. To be frank, the idea of changing memory (alloc stuff) seems "overwhelming" to me at first and I am having trouble finding just a simple example of here's a global 2d array declared at the top, and here's me editing its size with input/variables. Is there any way you could write this short code snippet up for me and explain it? All the other examples add way more parts to it and I am getting confused.

Comment: @Austin, I will take a look at this later this evening and let you know.

Comment: It would be much appreciated! Thank you!