# Converting 2d array C code to malloc

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, malloc

I made a program that adds two matrices and displays their sum with a max dimension of 100.

```
/* This program asks the user for 2 matrices called A and B, as integers,
   and displays their sum, C. The max dimension of each matrix is 100. */

#include <stdio.h>

// Construct function
void construct()
{
   int m, n, i, j;      // Variables
   int first[100][100], second[100][100], sum[100][100]; // Matrices variables

   printf("Please enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d", &m);
   printf("Please enter the number of columns: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   // User enters m x n amount whole numbers for the Matrix A
   printf("Enter Matrix A\n");
   for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         scanf("%d", &first[i][j]);

   // User enters m x n amount whole numbers for the Matrix B
   printf("Enter Matrix B\n");
   for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &second[i][j]);

   // Adds the sum of Matrix A and Matrix B
   for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         sum[i][j] = first[i][j] + second[i][j];

   // Display the sum of Matrix A and Matrix B
   printf("A + B =\n");
   for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         printf("%d ", sum[i][j]);

      printf("\n"); // Prints new line
   }

   return ;
}

// Main Function
int main()
{
    construct(); // Calls construct function
    return 0;
}
```

Now I need to change it so there is no max size for each matrix. 
So I need to use malloc to create my arrays.
So I cant use int A[rows][cols].
This is what I did to covert arrays to malloc. It compiles but it crashes after I entered all the integers. Need help.

```
/* This program asks the user for 2 matrices called A and B, as integers,
   and displays their sum, C. The max dimension of each matrix is 100. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Construct function
void construct()
{
   int m, n, i, j;      // Variables
   int *first = NULL;
   int *second = NULL;
   int *sum = NULL;    // Matrices variables

   printf("Please enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d", &m);
   printf("Please enter the number of columns: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   first = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
   second = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   sum = (int*)malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));


   // User enters m x n amount whole numbers for the Matrix A
   printf("Enter Matrix A\n");
   for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         scanf("%d", &first);

   // User enters m x n amount whole numbers for the Matrix B
   printf("Enter Matrix B\n");
   for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &second);

   // Adds the sum of Matrix A and Matrix B
   for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         sum = *first + *second;

   // Display the sum of Matrix A and Matrix B
   printf("A + B =\n");
   for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         printf("%d ", sum);

      printf("\n");
   }

   return ;
}

// Main Function
int main()
{
    construct(); // Calls construct function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984700/setup-a-2d-array-change-size-later-c/25984834#25984834

Comment: 1) the returned value from scanf() should always be checked to assure the input/conversion was successful. 2) in C, the returned value from malloc should not be cast.  3) the returned value from malloc should always be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this kind of line: 'canf("%d", &first);' will always put the input value in the same location in the malloc';d area,  specifically in the very first '4' bytes.\

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need to use malloc. Just move the array definitions to be after you have inputted `m` and `n`:

```
int first[m][n];

printf("Enter Matrix A\n");
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        scanf("%d", &first[i][j]);
```

and similarly for `second` and `sum`.

If the matrices might be larger than 100x100 then it might be good to use `malloc` to avoid the risk of a stack overflow; the way to do that is:

```
int (*first)[n] = malloc(m * sizeof *first);

printf("Enter Matrix A\n");
// etc.
```

and at the end, `free(first);`. No other changes are required.

---

In your attempt to use malloc, you didn't allocate enough space, and you didn't `scanf` into the space you allocated either (instead you overwrote the pointer to the allocated space).