# malloc for a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have declared a global array, `char *people[][2]`. The purpose of this array is to hold people's first and last names in the form of:

```
people[0][0]          = "John"           people[0][1]          = "Smith"
people[1][0]          = "Frank"          people[1][1]          = "Jones"
...                                      ...
people[NumOfNames][0] = "Lisa"           people[NumOfNames][1] = "Murray"
```

Where `NumOfNames` is an integer variable calculated in a function within my program. Once this value has been stored for `NumOfnames`, how can I use `malloc` to allocate memory to `people` so that it is of size `[NumOfNames]*[2]`?

Comment: First, I guess the actual names aren't actually literal strings, but read from somewhere? Secondly, to handle your problem you need two loops, one nested inside the other, for the allocations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, the names are read from a file. Would you mind elaborating on the nested loops idea? I'm very new to the `malloc` function.

Comment: Unless you really have to do it this way a better way is to use a struct that contains firstname and lastname. Then you only need a single dimension array to hold each person. And has the added advantage of being easily extendable for more person attributes (e.g. age, height, etc). You would just need to add more fields to the struct.

Comment: `people[NumOfNames-1][0] = "Lisa"` ?

Comment: `char *(*people)[2] = malloc(NumOfNames*sizeof(*people));`

Comment: take a look at this stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984700/setup-a-2d-array-change-size-later-c/25984834#25984834 with an answer that provides a function for a 2D array area that is malloced as well as links to some additional resources.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy once you know the syntax for multidimensional arrays:

```
size_t peopleCount = ...;
char* (*people)[2] = malloc(peopleCount*sizeof(*people));
```

Note that `people` here is, as always for `malloc()`ed arrays, a pointer to the first element of the array, i. e. a pointer to an array of two pointers to `char`. The `malloc()` call simply allocates memory for `peopleCount` such elements. By using this pointer type, you can use the `malloc()`ed array exactly the same way as you use the `people` array in your question.